# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed on lollipop for youtube v3 data api

Tags: java, android, api, youtube, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am using youtube v3 data api on android. I got exception from lollipop OS only not in other OS when using youtube v3 data api:

> "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Handshake failed"